# Data not printing to CSV file

Tags: python, selenium, csv, beautifulsoup

For some reason when I place this below code inside another For loop (not shown) the data won't print anything to the CSV file - however when the code is run outside of the main For loop it does print to CSV ok. Print(row) is working so I can see the correct data on screen.

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find('tbody', id="transactionsBody")
    tr = table.findAll(['tr'])
    for cell in tr:
        csvFile = open("booking_data.csv", 'wt', newline='', encoding='utf-8')
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
        td = cell.find_all('td')
        row = [i.text.replace('\n', '') for i in td]
        writer.writerow(row)
        print(row)
    csvFile.close()
```

Comment: why are you `opening cvfile` inside the `for cell in tr` loop & `closing it` outside the loop ?

Comment: the 1st 2 lines which you have declared inside `for cell in tr` loop can go outside of it - meaning `open the file, & create the writer object ` before the loop